# Would you believe the electron pushing theory in a conductor?

Tags: electric-circuits

Some people told me that, its the electrons doing all this current generating stuff. do the valence electrons really shift from one atom of the conductor to the other atom of it producing the drift of electrons due to the applied electric field?

An explanation of 1 or more para would be grateful :D

Comment: Not really. The wavefunction of an electron spreads in the entire material (we are assuming a good conductor like a metal), so it isn't localized to begin with.

Comment: could you please explain me a short explanation of the process involved @AccidentalBismuthTransform

Comment: It is the nature of metallic bonds. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding#:~:text=Metallic%20bonding%20is%20a%20type,and%20positively%20charged%20metal%20ions.

Comment: Thank you for the source..I'll go through it :D @BobD

Comment: One or more paragraphs kind of sound like a homework question. Please remember that that is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: Holes can also carry current (in both semiconductors and metals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the nature of metallic bonding that the conducting electrons are highly mobile. See: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding#:~:text=Metallic%20bonding%20is%20a%20type,and%20positively%20charged%20metal%20ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding#:%7E:text=Metallic%20bonding%20is%20a%20type,and%20positively%20charged%20metal%20ions)

It boils down to the inability of the positive ions in the metal to hold onto the outermost valence electrons which, in the absence of an electric field, move randomly because of thermal motion.

Hope this helps.